# Visual Studio editing cshtml resets Session

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

While debugging, when I edit .cshtml or .js files, Visual Studio destroys the session, and redirects to login page. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it causes the site to recompile and/or restart, which will recycle the website. That drops sessions if you're using the default in-proc (which is in memory of web server). If you need it to stick around, store it somewhere else, such as [options here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) (database, state server, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nikki. What I did was:

- Go to IIS > Session State
- In Session State, changed to `State Server`
- Connection String: `tcpip=localhost:42424`
- Time Out: `86400` i.e. 1 day

Restarted.

Note: All classes that are saved to Session need to be Serializable. Simply add `[Serializable]` before class declaration as below:

```
namespace App.Models
{

    [Serializable]
    public class User
    {

    }
}
```